# Loading a nested JSON file into UI Grid tables with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have a nested JSON file which keeps track of stations, and has nested fields about each  tank.

I am trying to allow the user to first select which gas station they want to see info from, and then load ONLY that stations information into a UI Grid table from angular. 
Code examples are much appreciated if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind select with ui-grid data with `$scope.selected`:

```
$scope.tankInfo = [];
    $scope.selected;

    $scope.onChange = function(){
      $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.tankInfo[$scope.selected];
    };

    $scope.initLoad = function () {
      $http.get('tankInfo.json').success(function (data) {
            $scope.selected = "Gas Station 1";
            $scope.tankInfo = data;
            $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.tankInfo[$scope.selected];
        });
    }
```

and your select:

```
  <select id="station" ng-model="selected"  ng-change="onChange()"
          ng-options="key as key for (key, value) in tankInfo"
   ></select>
```

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9Mj47BYWofQeIEsJrCbW?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: This is so simple and works perfect. Thanks so much, your solution really helped.